# Is there any key/value pair structure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to store information like:

*Pseudo-Code*

```
array(manager) = {"Prateek","Rudresh","Prashant"};
array(employee) = {"namit","amit","sushil"};
array(hr) = {"priya","seema","nakul"};
```

What kind of data structure can I use?

Comment: Not sure I follow, why can't you use a javascript array like : var managers = ["Prateek","Rudresh","Prashant"]; ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to store list of data ; and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) for key-value

In you case, you'd probably use both :

```
var data = {
    'manager': ["Prateek","Rudresh","Prashant"], 
    'employee': ["namit","amit","sushil"], 
    'hr': ["priya","seema","nakul"]
};
```

Here, `data` is an object ; which contains three arrays.

Answer (score 13):

An object:

```
var myobj = {
  "manager": ["Prateek","Rudresh","Prashant"],
  "employee": ["namit","amit","sushil"],
  "hr": ["priya","seema","nakul"]
}

alert(myobj['employee'][1]); // Outputs "amit"
```

Comment: Yes i think i was looking for it.

Comment: Did you mean for `{"Prateek","Rudresh","Prashant"}` to be an array?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I think he is wanting to use them as arrays.

Answer (score 10):

A normal object will do:

```
var a = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: ["value2.1","value2.2"]
    /*etc*/
}
```

Access with:

```
a.key1
a["key1"]
```

Answer (score 8):

With ES2015/ES6 you have [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) type.

Using Map your code will look like

```js
const map = new Map([
  ['manager', ['Prateek', 'Rudresh', 'Prashant']],
  ['employee', ['namit', 'amit', 'sushil']],
  ['hr', ['priya', 'seema', 'nakul']]
])

console.log(...map.entries())
```

To get Individual value you can use [Map.get('key')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) method

Answer (score 7):

you could store them in an array of objects:

```
    var Staff = [
       { name: 'Prateek', role: manager },
       { name: 'Rudresh', role: manager },
       { name: 'Prashant', role: manager },
       { name: 'Namit', role: employee },
       { name: 'Amit', role: employee },
       { name: 'Sushil', role: employee },
       { name: 'Priya', role: hr },
       { name: 'Seema', role: hr },
       { name: 'Nakul', role: hr },
    ];
```

adding an ID attribute might be useful too depending on your application. i.e

```
    { id: 223, name: 'Prateek', role: manager },
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use JSON like this. A little change of your pseudo code, but it will be serchable and extendable.

```
var Person = [
{
    "name": "Prateek",
    "position": "manager"},
{
    "name": "James",
    "position": "employee"}

];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:

```
var theArray = {};
theArray["manager"] = ["Prateek","Rudresh","Prashant"];
theArray["employee"] = ["namit","amit","sushil"];
theArray["hr"] = ["priya","seema","nakul"];
```

Comment: This is not correct, any object is that structure. Your example works because an array is just an object.

Comment: @Emil Ivanov: This is perfectly correct, it create a 2 dimensional array. please elaborate which part is incorrect

Comment: Arrays in Javascript can only be indexed by a number. Indexing them by string is possible, because any object in js can be indexed by a string.

Comment: i am very confused, so which part of my answer is wrong again?

Comment: @lbu - Run "JSON.stringify(theArray);" you will see that it returns an object containing 3 properties, which are arrays.  I think Emil's complaint is that naming an object "theArray" is misleading, it is helpful to understand theArray correctly as an object, not an array.  Yes your code works, but "2 dimensional array" concept is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Even you can use stuff as below :-

```
var obj = new Object();

obj.name = 'Jatin';
obj.place = 'Delhi';
```