# Jquery select value from json array

Tags: jquery, json

When I do `console.log(msg);`. My response is this `[{"test":"aaaaa"}].`

Now, How do I select aaaa.

Comment: Try: console.log(d.test); From where you get response? Can you place more code?

Comment: Not a very clear question... Give more code. What do you mean by 'How do I select aaaa'?

Comment: You want to retrieve that data somehow ?

Comment: @freshbm:msg.test says undefined.   obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg); console.log(msg.test); also says undefined.

Comment: @mrfishie:Let me know, what is not clear to you ?

Comment: @dyered then xdazz answer is the one to go.

Comment: Where is the `msg` variable defined? If you are simply using `console.log([{"test":"aaaaa"}])`, then you will need to put this value into a variable (`var msg = [{"test":"aaaaa"}]`), and then use that with xdazz's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

`msg` is an array, and the first element is `{"test": "aaaaa"}`

So you could do `msg[0].test` or `msg[0]['test']`

Comment: :It is not msg=[{"test":"aaaaa"}]. It is just [{"test":"aaaaa"}];

Answer (score 1):

From [Is there any key/value pair structure in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771763/is-there-any-key-value-pair-structure-in-javascript)

```
var myobj = {
  "managaner": ["Prateek","Rudresh","Prashant"],
  "employee": ["namit","amit","sushil"],
  "hr": ["priya","seema","nakul"]
}

alert(myobj['employee'][1]); // Outputs "amit"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $.each(msg, function(i, item){
    console.log(item.test);
 });
```

If you are getting your `json` response from some server or webservice then use it this way in your `ajax success function(){}`.

What going on with this is you have a json response as in array, so here `$.each()` is looping through the response it got from server then getting in the function with param `item` which is looping through the object. so at last `console.log(item.test)` is printing the object's property.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
msg[0].test
```

or

```
msg[0]["test"]
```

Comment: :It is not msg=[{"test":"aaaaa"}]. It is just [{"test":"aaaaa"}];

Answer (score 0):

I understand that  `msg=[{"test":"aaaaa"}]`

then u will have to take the value as `msg[0].test` . Then u can get "**aaaaa**"

Comment: :It is not msg=[{"test":"aaaaa"}]. It is just [{"test":"aaaaa"}];

Comment: watever it is .. from where you are getting [{"test":"aaaaa"}] . From the same variable, try to get the value

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
function(data) {
    var result = data[0];
    var was = result.was;
}
```