# Create array of arrays with dynamic names

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I want to create array for each user and store them in another array.
For that I used this code:

```
var arrs = [];
var userCount = 1;
@foreach($eventUsers as $user)
{
   arrs['arr' + userCount] = [];
   userCount++;
}
```

and console.log(arrs); gave me the output

```
[arr1: Array[0], arr2: Array[0], arr3: Array[0], arr4: Array[0]]
```

Then I need to push elements to each array(`arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4)` while looping through '`arrs`'

I tried using:

```
for (arr in arrs) {
    arr.push('x');
}
```

But didn't work. Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any key/value pair structure in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771763/is-there-any-key-value-pair-structure-in-javascript)

Comment: What language is this? In any case, instead of using keys `arr1` etc., just use array indexes.

Comment: @SNT93, did you disappear? This is the second question you've posted and then disappeared. You should accept questions if they answer your problem, so you can gain rep on the site, and support those who help you (And also let people know that we've solved your problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your array

```
var arrs = {}, i;
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    arrs['arr' + i] = [];
}
```

update the `arrs`

```
// iterate over the keys
for (i in arrs) {
    // make your assignment
    arrs[i].push('x');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer..

```
 for (key in arrs) {
  arrs[key].push("RRRRR");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an object:

```
var obj = {};
obj.test = "a string";
obj["test2"] = "another string";
console.log(obj);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members) post for how to loop though an object, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal) post for more info.